# Why do char array's in C not require a element specifier but integer array's do?

Tags: arrays, c, char

Why do char array's in C not require a element specifier but integer array's do?

For example:

```
  #include <stdio.h>                                                              
                                                                                   
  int main(void){                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                             
  char array1[100];                                                               
  int array2[100] = {1,2,3,4};                                                    
                                                                                   
  fgets(array1, 100, stdin);                                                      
  printf("%s", array1);    // This prints the string inputted without a specifier                                                       
                                                                                  
  printf("%d ", array2);  // This throws an error since there is no specifier                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays passed to functions [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to pointers.  The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to `char`, which is what you are passing, so all is well.  Likewise in the next line you are passing a pointer to `int`, but `%d` expects an actual `int`, not a pointer.  So it doesn't work.

The fundamental difference is that `%d` is meant to print a single integer, but `%s` is meant to print a whole array of characters (i.e. a string).